# Populate UITableView with list of files from Documents Directory in iPhone SDK 5.0

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing for iOS 5. What I would like to do is read the list of files in my app's Documents Directory and list them in the UITableView. I found an article on StackOverflow, but the API's used have been deprecated. Any ideas on what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the files of the directory into an `NSArray` and list them in the cells like this:

### cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

cell.textLabel.text = NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fileListAct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

*This still works in iOS5 and has not been deprecated.*

Comment: one more question.... this may be obvious but i am kind of new with tableviews. what is the indexpath.row? i can't seem to figure out what i put there. is this placeholder for something i haven't done yet?

Comment: **indexPath** refers to **`cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath `** in the method, **row** indicates the row for each file.